# ngx-translate не работает в продакшне

Tags: typescript

Проблема в том, что на локальном сервере все работает отлично - нет никаких претензий. Но после залива проекта в продакшн, на сайте весь переведенный мною ранее текст отображается именами свойств из json-файла перевода. При этом сам файл ru.json подгружается с сервера и имеет 200 респонз код. После входа на сайт, при попытке обновить страницу, он выкидывает обратно на Authpage. Все это (и вход, и редирект) сопровождаются ошибками 401 Unauthorised. Опять же, на локальном хосте все работает нормально.
Гуглил проблему, нашел примерно похожий случай - [вот он](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751913/ngx-translate-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2). Там есть пример кода, где человек нашел решение проблемы - он в интерсепторе поменял pipe на map. Я пытался сделать так же, но у меня (как и у него) ругается IDE. Однако он все же смог как-то это исправить и под вопросом приложил код решения. У меня так сделать не получается. Вот код моего интерсептора:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service';


@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private router: Router,
                private userService: UserService,) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<{}>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
    return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(tap(
            (event: HttpEvent<{}>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    // console.log('intercept event', event);
                }
            }, err => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    if (err.status === 401) {
                        this.userService.removeUser();
                        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
                        this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/login');
                    }
                }
            }
        ));
    }
}
```

Пытался сделать так:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service';


@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private router: Router,
                private userService: UserService,) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<{}>, next: HttpHandler): any {
        return next.handle(request)
            .map(
                (event: HttpEvent<{}>) => {
                    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                        // console.log('intercept event', event);
                    }
                }, err => {
                    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                        if (err.status === 401) {
                            this.userService.removeUser();
                            localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
                            this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/login');
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
    }
}
```

- вот на это ругается компилятор, именно на строчку

  ```
  .map(
  ```

Версия Angular - 6.0.3

Comment: блин, ну неужели вам настолько лень погуглить, вы же используете `pipeable` операторы, `handle(request).pipe(map( .... ))`

Comment: Отличный, конечно, совет, но учить меня гуглить предстоит не вам. Ваше решение я, конечно, тоже пробовал, причем в первую же очередь, но оно мне не помогло. Проблема оказалась в nginx-сервере, который запрашивал дополнительную атворизацию на продакшне. Мы ее отключили на время и все заработало.

Comment: учить вас гуглить предстоит вам самим, а не мне, а теперь еще раз всматриваемся в ваш вопрос `вот на это ругается компилятор, именно на строчку .map(`, не понимаю какое это имеет отношение к nginx